# Redefine double citation separator in apacite

Tags: apacite

I am using the \citep command with the apacite package but it's outputting something weird when double citing:

```
Otros países no cerraron nunca sus actividades, o lo hicieron de manera más tardía \citep{Cordero242021Jan}.
    
    \citep{Devlin2018Oct}
```

[image]

As it can be seen, the first one which is a double citation has no separator in the middle. I have tried changing the separator of authors using:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
    \renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}
    \renewcommand{\BBAB}{and}
    \renewcommand{\BAnd}{and}
    \renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{et. al.}  
}
```

However, only the \BOthers command works, the rest of them are not changing. How can I fix this so I can add a separator in the double citation?

Comment: Is there any chance you could show us a complete and compilable example document that reproduces the undesirable output from the screenshot with as little code as possible. I tried a very simple document and could not reproduce your troubles: https://gist.github.com/moewew/a9c9fc8389b45bd462a96a3bde09baf7